# Replica set reconfig is not work in mongo

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB atlas, I have a cluster with a replica set. In some point of time, I'm facing one issue, that is my primary and secondary replica set is switching automatically. I want to fix that issue. From MongoDB documents, i got one solution, `rs.reconfig()` command.
I tried to read existing configuration using `rs.config()`, but it's showing one error,

```
mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-xxxx:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxxx:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxxx:27017/admin?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username user --password pass
```

`rs.config()`
returns an error

```
 2019-02-28T11:37:42.251+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: Could not retrieve replica set config: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetConfig: 1.0, lsid: { id: {4 [87 2302 32 ]} }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: 564651465165165165, signature: { hash: [150 64 66 209 63 133 54], keyId: 5646545645614213.000000 } }, $db: \"admin\" }",
    "code" : 8000,
    "codeName" : "AtlasError"
} :
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your login user role.

To read the replica set configuration details, you need to be at least `clusterAdmin` role or you should have a `root` role.

In MongoDB Atlas, create a user as atlasAdmin

[image]

And use [Atlas API](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/clusters-modify-one/) to modify the replica set configuration.

> This is not available for free tier(M0 instance)

Comment: how we can set `root` role or `clusterAdmin` role in MongoAtlas Cluster

Comment: From MongoDB, I got one valid, `NOTE This feature is not available for M0 (Free Tier) clusters and has limited functionality for M2 and M5 clusters. For more information, see Atlas M0 (Free Tier), M2, and M5 Limitations.`                                Unfortunately, I'm using M0 (Free Tier). so I hope that it's not work in my Cluster. .. right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.. this is not available for the free tier(M0). I update the same in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some administrative commands are not available in Atlas clusters. Replica set reconfig is one of them. Please check [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands-paid-tier-clusters/#paid-tier-command-limitations) for more information.